# What is the Maven dependency for Directory API Client Library for Java?

Tags: java, maven, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

My maven project uses  Directory API Client Library for Java and i needed to include it as a dependency. But in [Directory API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/api-lib/java) page, under the Add Library to Your Project title when i select maven as my build environment it always showed,

"Add the following to your pom.xml file:

This library is in the process of uploading to the central Maven repository.  Please check back in a few hours."

for last couple of weeks.

Since i have used google drive dependency in another project as follows,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev60-1.13.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried to so the same by including,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-directory</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev28-1.17.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
```

but it didn't worked.

And for the recode my pom having following repository as well,

```
    <repository>
        <id>google-api-services</id>
        <url>http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>
```

What is the correct maven dependency to use Directory API Client Library for Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the page, there is a link as follows,

See [all versions available on the Maven Central Repository.](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.google.apis%22%20AND%20a%3a%22google-api-services-admin%22)

I have went through that page and found a previous version of Directory API Client Library for Java. By looking at it's pom i have tried following dependency and it worked.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-admin</artifactId>
        <version>directory_v1-rev22-1.16.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then I tried to update the version to latest as follows and also worked.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-admin</artifactId>
        <version>directory_v1-rev28-1.17.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
```